# Unity 5: Standard Assets are missing

Tags: c#, game-physics, unity-game-engine

I've just installed Unity 5 but doesn't come with any assets, like Character Controllers and such. Have I missed one step or something?

Thank you.
[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: You can download Standard Assests from asset store : [Standard Assets](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/32351).

Comment: @PawełMarecki: Then why not it come with Unity ... Is there any problem in installation ????

Comment: As i rememeber there is a check box during the instalation when you can check if you want to instal standard assets or not but you need to check cause im not sure. But package you can download from asset store is the same.

Comment: @PawełMarecki: Ok. Thanks Sir....

Comment: Note that the Standard Assets was for Unity4 and has not been updated. It brings a wave of warnings. You should only download the assets you need.

Answer (score 3):

During installation, be sure that the checkbox for "Standard Assets" is checked on the "Unity component selection" page.

[image]

[Source](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/5-3-released.372567/page-2#post-2414948)

Answer (score 1):

If you did not installed standard Assets while installing unity, you can still install from assets store. as mentioned here in docs

> Note: If you chose not to install Standard Assets when you installed Unity, you can download them from the [Asset Store](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/?&_ga=2.203533331.266387907.1516295579-641344812.1504029796#!/content/32351).

you can read [documentation at this link](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-InstallStandardAssets.html) for better and deep understanding.